# basic php form calculation issue

Tags: php, forms

I'm doing something probably very silly, wondering if I could get anyone to point out what I'm doing wrong. Teaching myself php, and in doing so I'm trying to make a wage calculator. It gives me these results:

```
Your results:
 29 years old earning
$205per day working
$5days a week at a
Your total earned money at age 65 is $0.
While your yearly income is
49200
```

The total earned money figure is not correct though, obviously. 0 isn't right.

Here's the full code

```
<?php

//get the values from the $_POST array

$age = $_POST['age'];
$days = $_POST['days'];
$pay = $_POST['pay'];



//calculate the total:

$howold = 65 - $age;
$retireageincome = $yearlyincome * $howold;
$yearlyincome = $pay * $days * 4 * 12;




//print out results

print "<p>Your results:<br>
<span class=\"number\">$age</span> years old earning <br>
$<span class=\"number\">$pay</span>per day working <br>
$<span class=\"number\">$days</span>days a week at a<br>
Your total earned money at age 65 is $<span class=\"number     
\">$retireageincome</span>.<br>
While your yearly income is <br>
<span class=\"number\">$yearlyincome</span>  </p>";

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at your code closely and/or turn on error reporting and you'll see your problem.

Comment: $retireageincome get calculated after $yearlyincome... i think your order is off...

Comment: Thank you. I actually didn't even realize order of variables there mattered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use `$yearlyincome` before the value of `$yearlyincome` is known.

Order of commands matters.  Move the

```
$yearlyincome = $pay * $days * 4 * 12;
```

to be before the line where `$yearlyincome` is used and you should see a non-0 value.